# highlight clicked country with chloropleth plot_ly R

Tags: r, plotly, shinyapps

I would like to highlight the country clicked on in an `R` map created with `plot_ly`. I've tried `highlight` and `highlight_key`.

```
library(tmap)
library(plotly)

data("World")

plot_ly(source = "map_world") %>%
  add_trace(type = "choropleth",
            locations = World$iso_a3,
            key = ~World$iso_a3,
            z = ~log2(World$pop_est),
            text = paste(World$name, "\n", World$pop_est),
            color = ~World$pop_est,
            hoverinfo = "text",
            marker = list(line = list(width = .3, color = "grey30" ))
  ) %>%
  highlight(on = "plotly_click", off = "plotly_doubleclick") %>% 
  highlight_key(~World$iso_a3)
```